# Assistance needed writing simple Objective-C program

Tags: objective-c, class, geometry

I have been struggling along with an online objective-c class for a few weeks now. I'm feeling very stupid..
My latest assignment is to write a program that demonstrates a class named Circle by asking the user for the circle's radius, creating a Circle object, and then reporting the circle's area, diameter, and circumference. 
We should have the following member variables:

```
radius:  a double
pi: a double initialized to 3.14159
```

and the following member functions:

```
setRadius - a mutator function for the radius variable
getRadius - an accessor function for the radius variable
getArea - returns the area of the circle, which is calculated as:    area = pi * radius * radius
getDiameter - returns the diameter of the circle, which is calculated as:   diameter = radius * 2
getCircumference - returns the circumference of the circle, which is calculated as:   circumference = 2 * pi * radius
```

The member variables of the class should be set as private.

Here is my program so far:

Main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        int radius;

        NSLog(@"Enter the circles radius:");
        scanf ("%d", &radius);





    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//circle class

@interface circle : NSObject

{ @private

-(double)      radius;
-(double)      pi;

}

@property int setRadius, getRadius;

-(double)      getArea;
-(double)      getDiameter;
-(double)      getCircumcerence;


@end
```

---

Implementation:

```
#import "circle.h"

@implementation circle

@synthesize setRadius, getRadius;


-(double) pi
{
    pi = 3.14159;
}

-(double) getArea
{
    pi * radius * radius;
}

-(double) getDiameter
{
    radius * 2;
}

-(double) getCircumcerence
{
    2 * pi * radius;
}
@end
```

As you can see, I haven't gotten very far. I am confused as how to simply utilize my methods in my main, and am sure I have already made mistakes.

Any advice is appreciated! I really need help, and am short on time.
Also, this may be far-fetched but if anyone could maybe skype with me and help me through it?
Thanks!

Comment: You should look into `@properties`.  As is, you'll need to add setter methods and `init` methods before you can do anything.

Comment: What's your native programming language?  Have you learned OOP in any language?  I don't want to downvote this, because there's not anything particularly wrong with the question, but a fully-fleshed out answer would be quite long.

Comment: is this meant to be a command line tool that can run on a mac? I work with objective-C but mainly on iphone. Let me know and I will try to help you out, with instruction of course ;)

Comment: nhgrif- I am very noob and don't know what you mean.

Comment: This is my first programming language. Also, yes I believe so William, I am using xcode within a mac virtual machine to write this.

Comment: myck Leave a comment here with @nhgrif So I can find your question later when I have more time to look at it and I'll see what I can do to help get you sorted out.  The @ is important.  It notifies me that someone has replied to me and sort of bookmarks this question for me.

Comment: @nhgrif Sorry new to the site! I appreciate your help!

Comment: myck, if one of the two posted answers is sufficient, you should mark one as accepted.  If they are not sufficient and you need some clarification, leave a comment either here or in reply to one of the answers with some explanation on what you're unclear about.

Comment: @myck Just a tip - if that online class is teaching you this type of Objective-C style, they probably aren't very experienced Objective-C developers and I'd be skeptical of their instruction.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Thanks for the tip. This class mostly consists of me teaching myself however. I am using Programming in Objective-C fifth edition by Stephan Kochan.

Comment: @myck OK, that is a good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are of course many ways to set this up.  I can remember being confused when starting out, below is an alternative example to give you something else to look at.

It is not intended to be fancy but just bare-bones so that you can see a minimal setup of the class with an initializer.

Note that the only value initialized is the const pi, of course, the radius can be initialized there as well, as nhgrif's example shows quite nicely.

Hope this helps!

```
//  Circle.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Circle : NSObject
{
    double radius;
    double pi;
}

@property double radius, pi;

-(double) getArea;
-(double) getDiameter;
-(double) getCircumference;

@end
```

And then the implementation:

```
//  Circle.m

#import "Circle.h"

@implementation Circle

@synthesize radius, pi;

// Initialize with const pi:
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        pi = 3.14159;
        NSLog(@"Circle created.");
    }
    return self;
}

-(double) getArea {
    return pi*radius*radius;
}

-(double) getDiameter {
    return 2*radius;
}

-(double) getCircumference {
    return 2*pi*radius;
}

@end
```

And then for main:

```
//  main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Circle.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Circle *aCircle = [[Circle alloc] init];

        // Use an arbitrary value:            
        [aCircle setRadius:2];

        NSLog(@"Area = %f",[aCircle getArea]);
        NSLog(@"Circumference = %f",[aCircle getCircumference]);
        NSLog(@"Diameter = %f",[aCircle getDiameter]);
        NSLog(@"Check pi = %f",[aCircle pi]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By convention in Objective-C only methods that return values by reference are prefixed with "get". `getArea`, `getDiameter`, `getCircumference` should be named: `area`, `diameter`, `circumference`

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, you should set up your `.h` to something more like this:

```
@interface Circle : NSObject

@property double radius;
@property (readonly) double area;
@property (readonly) double diameter;
@property (readonly) double circumference;
@property (readonly) double pi;

-(id)initWithRadius:(double)r;

+(instancetype)circleWithRadius:(double)r;

@end
```

This will set up a `setter` and `getter` for `radius` as well as `getters` for `area`, `diameter`, and `circumference`.  It also sets up an `init` and `factory` method for your `circle` which takes a double for the radius.

I will come back and edit in some modifications you need to make to your `.m` as well as your `main` file in order to make this work.  As a note, at a minimum we'll override the `getters` for the 3 `readonly` properties.  This will prevent the compiler from creating `ivars` (instance variables) for these properties (because we can just calculate and return the number we calculation when we call it).

In your `.m`:

```
#import Circle.h

@implementation Circle

-(id)initWithRadius:(double)r
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.radius = r;
    }
    return self;
}

+(instancetype)circleWithRadius:(double)r
{
    return [[Circle alloc] initWithRadius:r];
}

-(void)setRadius:(double)r  //This method is automatically created by @property
{  //include any verification logic (make sure r>0 etc), then...
    self.radius = r;
}

//we don't really need to override the radius getter

-(double)pi
{
    return 3.14159;  //or however much accuracy you want
}

-(double)area
{
    return (self.pi * self.radius * self.radius);
}

-(double)diameter
{
    return (2.0 * self.radius);
}

-(double)circumference
{
    return (self.diameter * self.pi);
}
```

In `main`, you use this `Circle` class in just the same way you use any other object in Objective-C (think about `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc).

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        double radius;

        NSLog(@"Enter the circles radius:");
        scanf ("%lf", &radius);

        Circle *myCircle = [Circle circleWithRadius:radius]; //the factory method we set up

        NSLog(@"myCircle radius: %lf", myCircle.radius);
        NSLog(@"myCircle area: %lf", myCircle.area);
        NSLog(@"myCircle diameter: %lf", myCircle.diameter);
        NSLog(@"myCircle circumference: %lf", myCircle.circumference);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now I just wish I could follow your explanation better.. I still have a ways to go with my learning @_@

Comment: @myck I'll explain more of it as I edit it in.  I've now included the `.m` that corresponds to this `.h`.  Let me know what's confusing so far.  So far, we're not to the point of calling anything in main yet.

Comment: I think I just need to spend some more time studying the vocabulary.

Comment: @myck If you have any questions specifically, just let me know.  Apple's Objective-C documentation is very helpful.