# How do I define a variable with user entered data within the implementation?

Tags: objective-c, implementation

I hope that makes sense. I'm trying to define radius, as something the user enters. How would I do this?

```
#import "circle.h"

@implementation circle

-(double) radius {
    double radius = 
}

-(double) pi {
    double pi = 3.14159;
    return pi;
}

@synthesize setRadius, getRadius;

-(double) getArea {
    double area = pi * radius * radius;
    return area;
}

-(double) getDiameter {
    double diameter = 2 * radius;
    return diameter;
}

-(double) getCircumcerence {
    double circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
    return circumference;
}
@end
```

Here is a sentence of nothing so it will let me post my question for not being mostly code.

Comment: sorry your question and code does not make sense to me

Comment: myck, you should spend some more time looking at the answers to your previous question.  If you have any questions, post a comment to one of the answers.  You have two very good samples of how to set up classes in Objective C there for this exact class.  I'm not sure what you're unclear about, but would be glad to help you if you could post a comment there specifying what's unclear.  Moreover... you haven't even accepted one of the perfectly good answers to your previous question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assistance needed writing simple Objective-C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775776/assistance-needed-writing-simple-objective-c-program)

Comment: Thanks nhgrif and @bladebunny.. Sorry if this post was redundant. I come asking a quick question and there ends up being so many other problems with my code that need to be addressed.. I'm feeling mighty overwhelmed. But again, thanks guys.

Comment: @myck we all have to learn sometime.  Don't be put off.  I think we/I got a bit side-tracked but you should have your answer.  As suggested, if things still seem confusing, i would highly recommend getting and reading the Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming guide (if you don't already have it).  It is very well written, thorough and easy to follow.  And doesn't assume too much in terms of prior experience. http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_

Comment: First you have to define "user" and "enters".  If the user is another method that's one thing -- just pass the value as a parameter or property.  But if the user is a real person then you have to define a mechanism to enter the value -- some sort of data entry widget.

Comment: myck, if your question has been answered (here and on your other question), you need to accept one of the answers.  If it has not, you need to post comments to the available answers to request clarification on what you're confused about.  Please don't post any more new questions until you've accepted answers to your two currently open questions.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer because I misread the original question.  Let me state what I assume you are trying to do:

Set the value of a property called 'radius' on an Objective C class.
Interface (header) should have something like:

```
  @property (nonatomic, assign) double radius;
```

You are synthesizing the property and I will assume you want/need to do that. But your syntax is wrong.  It should be:

```
    @synthesize radius;
```

The instance variable, by default will be: _radius

So, your setter would be:

```
- (void)setRadius:(double)radius
{
   _radius = radius;
}
```

A getter might look like:

```
-(double)radius
{
    return _radius;
}
```

You can set a different backing variable in the @synthesize statement if you like, by default you will get _radius

Keep in mind that unless you have some custom logic you need in your setter and getter that you don't need to define those methods at all.  Nor, by default, do you even need to synthesize the property.  The compiler will take care of all of that.

Further info:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html

Comment: what are you trying do to?

Comment: Thanks @bladebunny ! Is radiusWithInput a new method?

Comment: Edited answer is now significantly better, and as such irrelevant comments have been removed.  As a historical note, everything in both your and my answer has been more than covered in complete detail as answers to the previous question asked by this user.  In the previous question, I went the route of `@properties`... so I tried the other way this time...

Comment: Sorry.  And thanks. Lesson learned about not pulling the trigger too fast. And thanks for the clean up.  Did not realize there was a 'cross post'. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as a method in your `circle` class:

```
-(void)setRadius:(double)input {
    radius = input;
}
```

Assuming you're not using `@properties`, which I highly recommend (and provided an example of in answer to your other question), this is how you properly create a `setter` in Objective-C.  `radius` needs to be declared as a variable of the class, outside this method, so that it can be called by your other methods such as `getCircumference` etc.

---

In order to create a private instance variable, you need to tack this on to the end of your `@implementation` line:

```
@implementation circle {
    double radius;
}
```

But again, doing this assumes you haven't gone the route of `@properties`, which again, I highly recommend.

---

To make use of this from main:

```
circle *myCircle = [[circle alloc] init];
[circle setRadius:1.0];  //the radius is now 1.0
double newRadius = 27.0;
[circle setRadius:newRadius];  //now the radius is 27.0
```

Comment: @BryanChen I've edited once or twice now since your comment.  If you don't think this explanation is sufficient, you'll have to elaborate on what I haven't fully explained.

Comment: @Bladebunny Bryan didn't ask the original question.